# IF statement being ignored. Function not supposed to execute when IF is not fulfilled, but still does

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm not sure why my IF statement is being ignored. The function is not supposed to execute if the IF statement is not being met. Here's the code:

```
function myFormSubmit(e) {
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var type = e.values[2];
  var taxNumber = e.values[3];
  var title = e.values[15];  
  var surname = e.values[16];
  var fullNames = e.values[17];
  var ID = e.values[18];

  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1pWe4TBF3_mlqglfoIrTO8d6O2fSra27lPt0Iy9Tjwjw");

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("17F678vzKcE7AaVqef0k-f96uHCOJeotv");

  var copy = file.makeCopy(surname + ',' + fullNames, folder);

  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

  var body = doc.getBody();

  if (type = "Personal Financial Services") {

  body.replaceText("{{FullNames}}", fullNames);
  body.replaceText("{{Surname}}", surname);
  body.replaceText("{{ID}}", ID);
  body.replaceText("{{IncomeTaxNumber}}", taxNumber);
  body.replaceText("{{Title}}", title)

  doc.saveAndClose();
  }
}
```

Comment: `=` is for assignment, `==` and `===` are for comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are missing one equal sign in your if condition. For comparisons you need two or three ("==" or "===") where "===" is for strict comparison.

Replace your if condition with this line:

```
if (type == "Personal Financial Services") {...}
```

---

**References:**

[MDN comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Answer (score 0):

one equal sign is assignment

eg `var type = "somevalue"`

for equalty use == or === sign

in your case value is assigned to type variable so that ie true.